# $http.get with AngularJS on Windows Phone 8

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, cordova, windows-phone-8

I am trying to GET data from an external API with AngularJS, but after several hours of testing different methods of fetching the data I'm out of ideas, I made this code for testing:

```
        alert("sending!!");
        $http.get('http://www.google.com')
        .then(function(res){
        alert("success!");
        }, function(err){
        //error
            alert(err);
        }).catch(function(err){
        //catch
         alert(err);
        });
        alert("sent!!");
```

This code shows only the "sending" and "sent" alert, I compile my app with PhoneGap Build and it works perfect(shows the success alert) on Android, iOS and FireFox OS devices. Also on Android, iOS AND Windows Phone 8 for the PhoneGap Developer App, aswell for Chrome, FF and IE. So its only failing on the actual Windows Phone 8 device, the device is fully connected to the internet.

I use the access origin "*" in my config.xml

Anyone managed to do $http.get on a Windows Phone 8 device with AngularJS $http? If so how?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Facing the same problem. Any luck finding any solution?